# Have a method that may or may not be async. How to handle?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a method that either gets a Token back for by checking all their credentials or by using a refresh token.

```
  public TokenDto GenerateAuthToken(TokenRequestDto dto)
        {
            switch (dto.GrantType)
            {
                case "password":
                    return GetToken(dto.ClientId, dto.Email, dto.Password); 
                case "refresh_token":
                    return GetRefreshToken(dto.RefreshToken);
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }
```

GetToken is async as I am using asp.net identity and the build in methods are async. GetRefreshToken has nothing async.

Should I just mark GetRefreshToken as async or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `GetRefreshToken` is a synchronous method, I wouldn't lie about it by marking it as a `Task<T>`. Instead, I would rather have the caller use a completed task

```
public Task<TokenDto> GenerateAuthToken(TokenRequestDto dto)
{
    switch (dto.GrantType)
    {
        case "password":
            // asynchronous, return the task
            return GetToken(dto.ClientId, dto.Email, dto.Password); 
        case "refresh_token":
            // synchronous, use a completed task
            return Task.FromResult(GetRefreshToken(dto.RefreshToken));
        default:
            // don't return null, throw instead
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(dto.GrantType));
    }
}
```

Comment: Are there any advantages to using `Task.FromResult` rather than marking the method `async` and using an `await` on the `GetToken` call?

Comment: @gunr2171 Well, using `async/await` generates a state machine at compile time and while the hit is minimal, you can avoid it when you don't have a continuation (i.e the `await` call is the last part of the method). Both are valid approaches though